# writing linq query SiteMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've a MyDataTable. It has a column with name `Title`

```
DataTable dtTmp = new GetDatas(); /* GetDatas function returns MyDataTable type*/

rptImages.DataSource = SiteMap.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>().Where(x => x.Title != /*dtTmp[index]["Title"]*/);
```

I want to coded if x.title not equel dtTmp any item's `Title` value.

How to coded easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use:

```
rptImages.DataSource = SiteMap.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>().Where(
    x => dtTmp.Select("Title='"+x.Title.Replace("'","''")+"'").Length==0);
```

you get items not found in the The title column.